# mysql count consiquence rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

guys. I have a table like:

```
date_time_stamp         | value
________________________
01.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
02.01.2001 01:01:00     | foo
02.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
03.01.2001 01:01:00     | foo
04.01.2001 01:01:10     | test
04.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
05.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
```

i want to count how many tests there is, but counting only the latest consequence,

but counting only

```
04.01.2001 01:01:10 | test
```

and

```
05.01.2001 01:01:00 | test
```

because they are the latest consequence and have no dublicates in date. if there is a duplicate - you need to count only the latest one. Are there any ways of doing this? or may be there is another solution? also want to add that value is a set.

Comment: so you want to get total count of latest `test` for all days i.e. single `test` for each day which is latest on that day?

Comment: 01.01.2001 01:01:00  would appear to meet your definition for counting.

Comment: Your English is not good, what does "latest consequence" mean?

Comment: I need only last sequence of rows, containing test, and if there are two rows with same date, i need to count only the newest one. So a query should return me "2 rows" or smth like that. Also it is a DATETIME column.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Below will give you the latest date_time_stamp which has `test` value for each day. MAX() is an aggregate function and works with date and time.

```
SELECT MAX(date_time_stamp), value from TABLE_NAME
WHERE value = 'test'
GROUP BY date_time_stamp
ORDER BY date_time_stamp
```

Output would be of type ...

```
MAX(date_time_stamp)    | value
_______________________________
01.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
02.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
04.01.2001 01:01:10     | test
05.01.2001 01:01:00     | test
```

If you just want the count of `test` and only picking latest consequence on each day then below should help ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT MAX(date_time_stamp) from TABLE_NAME
      WHERE value = 'test'
      GROUP BY date_time_stamp)
```

Output would be of type ...

```
COUNT(*)
________
4
```

`NOTE:` Above works on assumption that column date_time_stamp is of DATETIME datatype else you would have to use couple of functions (REPLACE, STR_TO_DATE) to get it in DATETIME format.

`Sample Data`: having orderDates and employeeId who processed it. For demo, we will be picking employeeId=4 who has processed more than 1 order on same day, here as there is no time so there will be duplicates and MAX will unaffected by duplicates as it will always picks maximum value even if there are duplicates.

[image]

`Output of 1st Query`: Only get latest orders for the day, processed by employeeId=4

[image]

`Final Query`: total count of orders processed by employeeId=4, pick only latest order for each day.

[image]

You can try all the queries at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

Comment: It makes no sense to group by the same column you're aggregating. It should be `GROUP BY value`.

Comment: as far as i understood he needs rows with only `test` as value and he only needs the latest sequence. `i want to count how many tests there is, but counting only the latest consequence`. Above queries result would anyways gives total count of rows with `test` value.

Comment: It still makes no sense to use `MAX(col)` with `GROUP BY col`. All the values in the group have the same value, so the max is that value.

Comment: `MAX(col)` with `GROUP BY(col)` is to get only the latest consequence for that day and WHERE clause is to take only rows with `test` as value. Finally the `COUNT(*)` will give the total count of `test`.

Comment: Maybe you mean `GROUP BY DATE(date_time_stmp)` so you get the last time on each day.

Comment: Yes, I haven't used the DATE casting as the actual data in the question is not of standard DATE format (should have hyphens and not dots) so @CMDR has to take care of casting to ensure date_time_stamp is treated as DATE. One option would be to use REPLACE(date_time_stamp, '.', '-') before casting to DATE.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that the column is a `DATETIME`. He needs to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert it, since even replacing `.` will not produce a date that MySQL can parse by default.

Comment: Yes, Updated the post with clarification. Thanks Barmar!

Comment: Thanks down voter, good job on down voting the solution but up voting comments! You keep us motivated to even attempt answering questions :)

Comment: Yes, JRG, i need only last sequence of rows, containing test, and if there are two rows with same date, i need to count only the newest one. Also it is a DATETIME column

Comment: Thanks for confirmation CMDR, above query should give you expected results i.e. pick only latest sequence of row for a day. If the above query satisfies your needs or provides you enough pointers to go to next step then please upvote and/or accept my answer. Thanks again!